# Python search for string in cmd window

Tags: python, cmd, minecraft

Hi I have a `python program` I'm making for a friend, he wants a small program to monitor his `Minecraft server` in a `cmd` window and write to an `excel document` whenever someone logs on. I've looked everywhere and I just cant work out how to get `python to monitor a cmd window`, I can get the search function and writing to an excel document but I have no idea with the cmd window. Is there something I'm missing, some hidden command I've missed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could look into `subprocess` module. It might help.

Comment: I don't know how the server works, but it might be possible to redirect it's output to a file and get a python process to monitor the file.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to scrape a command window or parse STDOUT, why not just watch `output-server.log` for connections?